# Hide a div based on value of a submit button

Tags: jquery

I'm looking to hide a submit button with a value of 'foo', **but only if** the div it resides within has a class of 'foo2'.

The following jQuery does half the job, hiding the submit button if it contains 'foo' in its value, however it works across the board, if its within foo2 or not.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("input[value=foo]").closest('div').hide();
});
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You want to hide the button or the whole div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you needed was to call the div with its class name

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("input[value=foo]").closest('div.foo2').hide();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the requirements for the div to the `closest` selector:

```
$("input[value=foo]").closest('div.foo2').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably cleaner to modifiy the selector rather than the .closest operator. In case there is actually another div with the foo2 class:

```
$(".foo2 input[value=foo]").closest('div').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to hide the button but not the whole div:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("div.foo2 input[value=foo]").closest('div.foo2').find("input[value=foo]").hide();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
$('div.foo2').has('input[value=foo]').hide()
```